# How to create a VBA form to match excel value to the name of the worksheet in the same workbook?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I am working on a self created VBA form. It has submit button and takes in entries such as destination, timing and budget.

I have a excel worksheet named "bali". it consists of the destination's available airline, timing and budget.

I would like to create a method that could get the inserted destination, eg. bali, when the user clicked submit button and then match it to display and show the content of the worksheet named "bali" in another new sheet or a form.

Anyone could help me with this by providing a step by step code ?

Comment: Can you tell us what you've already tried? SuperUser is a place where we try to help those who themselves have tried to resolve something, but get stuck or run into a problem. Any examples of code you're using helps too. You improve your chances of getting a response if you provide details of what you've already tried. This does two things; 1) lets us know you are willing to put in an effort and not expect someone else to just do it for you, and 2) helps us to not suggest what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

This is for the reference code for the simple form which i have.

Private Sub cmdCancel_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub ResetComboBox_Click()
    Dim ctl As Control
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(ctl) = "TextBox" Or TypeName(ctl) = "ComboBox" Then
    ctl.Value = ""
    ElseIf TypeName(ctl) = "CheckBox" Then
    ctl.Value = False
    End If
    Next ctl
End Sub

Private Sub SubmitComboBox_Click()
 If Me.DestinationComboBox.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please choose a destination.", vbExclamation, "Travel Destination"
        Me.DestinationComboBox.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

```
 If Me.DateTextBox.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please select a date.", vbExclamation, "Travel Date"
    Me.DateTextBox.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

If Not IsDate(Me.DateTextBox.Value) Then
    MsgBox "The Date field must contain a date.", vbExclamation, "Travel Date"
    Me.DateTextBox.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

 If Me.BudgetTextBox.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please insert your budget.", vbExclamation, "Travel Budget"
    Me.BudgetTextBox.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

If Not IsNumeric(Me.BudgetTextBox.Value) Then
    MsgBox "The budget field must contain number.", vbExclamation, "Travel Budget"
    Me.BudgetTextBox.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Dim RowCount As Long
RowCount = Worksheets("Parameters").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
With Worksheets("Parameters").Range("A1")
    .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.DestinationComboBox.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 1).Value = Me.DateTextBox.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 2).Value = DateValue(Me.DateTextBox.Value)
    .Offset(RowCount, 3).Value = Me.BudgetTextBox.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 4).Value = Me.BudgetTextBox.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 5).Value = Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:ss")
End With

Dim ctl As Control
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(ctl) = "TextBox" Or TypeName(ctl) = "ComboBox" Then
    ctl.Value = ""
    ElseIf TypeName(ctl) = "CheckBox" Then
ctl.Value = False
End If
Next ctl
End Sub